# Как добавить XML output formatter в ASP.Net Boilerplate?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-mvc, aspnetboilerplate

Используется ASP.NET Core 2.2, ASP.Net Boilerplate 4.1, Modul Zero Core 4.4.0.
WebAPI поддерживает JSON как входной и выходной тип данных. Передо мной встала задача добавить поддержку XML формата для взаимодействия со сторонними приложениями.
Что я пробовал:

```
// file RootNs.Web.Mvc Startup.cs
public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {
    // ...
    services.AddMvc(options => {

        options.Filters.Add(new AutoValidateAntiforgeryTokenAttribute());

        options.ReturnHttpNotAcceptable = true;
        options.OutputFormatters.RemoveType<HttpNoContentOutputFormatter>();
        options.RespectBrowserAcceptHeader = true;

        options.OutputFormatters.Add(new XmlSerializerOutputFormatter());
        // и так пробовал
        // options.OutputFormatters.Add(new XmlDataContractSerializerOutputFormatter());

        options.FormatterMappings
        .SetMediaTypeMappingForFormat("xml", MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("application/xml"));
    })
}
```

После этого декорировал метод в WebAPI атрибутом FormatFilter, но кроме HTTP ошибок ничего не получал.

Как добавить XML тип для входных и выходных данных?

Comment: [AddXmlSerializerFormatters](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/advanced/formatting?view=aspnetcore-2.2#adding-xml-format-support) ? Пример: [тыц](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50594973/5045688)